# .NET 5 HttpClient: SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: c#, .net-5, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to get an image from a public url. I did a test in Postman and I can get it without any issues, as well as in my dev pc. When I publish it to production web server, I got the error: "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.", right after GetByteArrayAsync().
Inner Exception:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'ProtocolVersion'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090326): The message received was unexpected or badly formatted. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm) at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This is the code that is working in my dev pc:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
var result = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("url");
```

Since this code is not working in production, I have added (and still not working):

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "deflate");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "br");
```

And also using HttpRequestMessage and HttpClientHandler, I got the same issue in production:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "url"))
{
request.Headers.Host = "url";
using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
 {
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
 }
```

So, do you know what the issue in production would be? why this works in dev and Postman but not in production? do I need to set up a setting?
Also, when I change the target to another public url, I can get an image from production server without issues.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are the "inner" exception messages?

Comment: What OS is the production web server running? Is it different from your dev PC?

Comment: Also, the OS on web server is Windows 2019 Datacenter. Dev PC: Windows 10 Enterprise Edition

Comment: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =...` why do you have this line? It's unnecessary, and can cause more problems than it solves. And `DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator`  is quite obviously *dangerous*.. Can you post the URL so we can test it?

Comment: Hmmm server supports a wide range of ciphers https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=servicio.indecopi.gob.pe&hideResults=on so unclear exactly what's going on. Use Wireshark to see the Server Hello and Client Hello packets, and try analyze what's happening. And try upgrading to .NET 6 as .NET 5 is now out of support.

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for that tool. I see for the one that works, it shows protocols TLS 1.3 and 1.2 as Yes. For the one that doesn't work, only shows TLS 1.3 as yes. I will upgrade to .NET 6. thanks

Comment: You should also use the IIS Crypto tool to make sure TLS 1.3  and associated ciphers are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Charlieface for the SSLLab report I found out that the target server was working with TLS 1.3 only, and my web hosting provider was working with Windows 2019 where that protocole is not available. So, I changed the hosting provider with Window 2022 and my web app is working fine.
Thanks.